# Laravel 5.1 Amazon SQS: Exception SignatureDoesNotMatch Signature expired

Tags: exception, laravel-5.1, amazon-sqs

I have configured Queues in Laravel 5.1 using Amazon SQS and it worked fine for the first time but afterwards it is giving following error:

> "Error executing \"SendMessage\" on \"queue_url\"; AWS HTTP error:
>   Client error: 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): Signature expired:
>   20151019T195353Z is now earlier than 20151020T101301Z
>   (20151020T102801Z - 15 min.) - Sender`SignatureDoesNotMatch`Signature
>   expired: 20151019T195353Z is now earlier than 20151020T101301Z
>   (20151020T102801Z - 15
>   min.)"

It seems like timestamp associated for the request is being constantly used. How can I configure it in Laravel?

Following how I am queueing test email:

```
/**
 * Send an e-mail reminder to the user.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function sendEmailReminder(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    // $this->dispatch(new SendReminderEmail($user));
    try {
        Mail::queue('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
        });
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        throw ($ex);
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
    'sqs' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key'    => 'key',
        'secret' => 'secret',
        'queue'  => 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx/jobs[queue_name]',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was occurring due to the wrong datetime set on my debian machine. I have changed the timezone and corrected datetime and it worked fine.

```
date --set 1998-11-02 
date --set 21:08:00
```

Set the time automatically

```
apt-get install ntp
```

https://wiki.debian.org/DateTime#Set_the_time_automatically

[Laravel 5 Amazon AWS S3 Error: Client error: 403 RequestTimeTooSkewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096687/laravel-5-amazon-aws-s3-error-client-error-403-requesttimetooskewed)